Microsoft Graph User Division
How should I request the User employeeOrgData.division using the Microsoft Graph SDK?
Here's my code...
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "User.Read.All" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> GridView()
{
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();
    queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
    queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$expand", "manager($levels=1;$select=displayName)"));
    queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$select", "onPremisesSamAccountName,displayName,mail,jobTitle,department,surname,givenName,streetAddress,city,state,postalCode,businessPhones,mobilePhone,employeeOrgData.division"));    

    var results = await _graphServiceClient.Users
        .Request(queryOptions)
        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
        .Filter("employeeType eq 'Employee'")
        .GetAsync();

    //CONCATENATES THE PAGED RESULTS
    var users = new List<User>(results.CurrentPage);
    users.AddRange(results.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());

    while (results.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        results = await results.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        users.AddRange(results.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
    }

    //SORT BY LAST, FIRST
    users = users
        .DistinctBy(u => u.Id)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Surname)
        .ThenBy(x => x.GivenName).ToList();

    return View("GridView", users);
}

I've tried selecting both employeeOrgData and employeeOrgData.division. In both cases it's always null.
I've tried expanding employeeOrgData, but it's not exapandable.

Try adding the employeeOrgData into the user properties using POST request and then try fetching them...When you create a user you may not have that option(division,costCentre) in the portal but you can add the Org details through Graph API. See this documentation.

@ShivaKeshavVarma the division is populated for every user in our tenant. It should not be null.

Works fine for me with employeeOrgData in $select. What permissions have granted to your app?

@user2250152 User.Read.All  Do I need additional permissions for employeeOrgData?

If you can try Directory.Read.All permission, but I also have only User.Read.All

@user2250152 we got it sorted.  Figured out that Division was populated in our onPrem AD and that wasn't flowing into Entrada.  Had to update the AAD Sync to push Division into employeeOrgData.division, and that did the trick.
